# render a scene with number of N lights with different types

Tags: opengl

If I need to draw number of N lights with a scene, the light type may be spot/point/directional or sky-light and each light casting a shadow, render it use **opengl es 2.0**.

One pass is not enough to do this, so I heared the multi-pass lighting, but I dont know how to implement it.

My idea now is: grouping lights by its type, then loop each group and render the scene to RT, final blend (use add blend or multiply?) all RT to the color buffer. But I think the RGB value  in color buffer will overflow.

So, I dont know how to do, cannot defered shading, no light pre-pass, no float texture no HDR.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi-pass lighting, you will probably need to use a combination of additive **and** multiplicative blending. This is because for each light, you want to accumulate the diffuse and specular terms and then at the end you will multiply the accumulated lighting by the base material properties.

You are absolutely right, in most cases unless you are super careful with your lights the computed diffuse value will exceed **1.0** at some point. It will not overflow *per-se*, since it is floating-point, but it will be ***clamped*** to **1.0** before it is written to the color buffer.

Without HDR, your best bet is probably to alter the attenuation coefficients so that lights falloff more quickly. This will reduce the size of the super-bright areas to very close to your light source and the effect will be something like non-HDR specular highlights (small patches of washed out color).